# S3 SignatureDoesNotMatch for videos on Android

Tags: android, amazon-s3, webview, rocket.chat

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAQZMEKQWT6XKITXWX</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20190416T080255Z
20190416/ap-southeast-1/s3/aws4_request
81868020072abb4296cb5afe86eff8b9e46f3d17e3498314b612381fc71811a2</StringToSign><SignatureProvided>8e2511d204a429634b3be3f689de16dcf86b23e73f604fcdd32afee9e4bc1421</SignatureProvided><StringToSignBytes>41 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 2d 53 48 41 32 35 36 0a 32 30 31 39 30 34 31 36 54 30 38 30 32 35 35 5a 0a 32 30 31 39 30 34 31 36 2f 61 70 2d 73 6f 75 74 68 65 61 73 74 2d 31 2f 73 33 2f 61 77 73 34 5f 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 0a 38 31 38 36 38 30 32 30 30 37 32 61 62 62 34 32 39 36 63 62 35 61 66 65 38 36 65 66 66 38 62 39 65 34 36 66 33 64 31 37 65 33 34 39 38 33 31 34 62 36 31 32 33 38 31 66 63 37 31 38 31 31 61 32</StringToSignBytes><CanonicalRequest>GET
/GKArc54d3muDW9Y5D/uploads/moCDvfbSHu35pfPu2/TqcNP5irDSNzEY3gr/CEsA9yT9HdiwFSJ9m
X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=AKIAQZMEKQWT6XKITXWX%2F20190416%2Fap-southeast-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20190416T080255Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=1200&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
host:rc-test-glg.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com:443

host
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD</CanonicalRequest><CanonicalRequestBytes>47 45 54 0a 2f 47 4b 41 72 63 35 34 64 33 6d 75 44 57 39 59 35 44 2f 75 70 6c 6f 61 64 73 2f 6d 6f 43 44 76 66 62 53 48 75 33 35 70 66 50 75 32 2f 54 71 63 4e 50 35 69 72 44 53 4e 7a 45 59 33 67 72 2f 43 45 73 41 39 79 54 39 48 64 69 77 46 53 4a 39 6d 0a 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 41 6c 67 6f 72 69 74 68 6d 3d 41 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 2d 53 48 41 32 35 36 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 43 72 65 64 65 6e 74 69 61 6c 3d 41 4b 49 41 51 5a 4d 45 4b 51 57 54 36 58 4b 49 54 58 57 58 25 32 46 32 30 31 39 30 34 31 36 25 32 46 61 70 2d 73 6f 75 74 68 65 61 73 74 2d 31 25 32 46 73 33 25 32 46 61 77 73 34 5f 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 44 61 74 65 3d 32 30 31 39 30 34 31 36 54 30 38 30 32 35 35 5a 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 45 78 70 69 72 65 73 3d 31 32 30 30 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 53 69 67 6e 65 64 48 65 61 64 65 72 73 3d 68 6f 73 74 0a 68 6f 73 74 3a 72 63 2d 74 65 73 74 2d 67 6c 67 2e 73 33 2e 61 70 2d 73 6f 75 74 68 65 61 73 74 2d 31 2e 61 6d 61 7a 6f 6e 61 77 73 2e 63 6f 6d 3a 34 34 33 0a 0a 68 6f 73 74 0a 55 4e 53 49 47 4e 45 44 2d 50 41 59 4c 4f 41 44</CanonicalRequestBytes><RequestId>2674C76BC597C0A1</RequestId><HostId>AKOxOil47vITp9xDwfAQsKilU8EYjz+x2/ZInCKiEdmQ+mt6Vzd9VAw1cYemxNOl9W4hyjvHP1k=</HostId></Error>
```

I am using S3 for file uploads.

It works fine for video, images on Android and it works fine for videos, audio, images on iOS. Please help figure out why this only for videos on Android. Thanks.

Comment: Compare the displayed "String to Sign" against the parameters you used when signing the request.  Is there anything you specified that is absent here?  Are there any `SignedHeaders` in your signed URL (or `Authorization` header) that are absent here?  For example, `content-type`?

Comment: Oooo `host:....com:443` also seems suspicious.  I would not expect to see an explicit `:443`.